# Installing a Linux distribution on Apple TV 2

Tags: linux

I want to hook up an Apple TV 2 (the second, small black version) to my 58" Samsung television, and want to use an RDP client that comes built into Google Chrome to control the Apple TV from my Macbook Air.

This would effectively enable me to 'remote' my tv using my computer.

The only questions that I have are as follows:

1. Do you have any tips or recommendations as to how effectively I can root Apple TV, remove the iOS build, and install another operating system on it?
2. Which OS should I replace with the iOS build? I just checked to find that even Ubuntu demands 1GB of RAM, whereas the Apple TV only has 128MB of RAM, with a 1Ghz A4 Processor.

Answer (score 2):

The task may not be an easy one. You must first decide whether or not you are ready to be forced to dig into understanding the mechanics of a Linux system. Be aware that such non-standard usage of *any* Linux distribution will potentially produce far more problems than can be experienced with standard PCs. Furthermore, the user base of such projects is incomparably smaller than in "standard" Linux use cases.

Do not take me wrong - I don't want to discourage you, but to rise your awareness of what it takes to do what you attempt. It all depends on the type of person you are. The task may just go smoothly if you strictly follow instructions, but it may also turn out problematic at some points and require a lot of stubbornness to solve the issues.

That being said, I suggest that your choice of Linux distribution should mainly depend on how much information you can find on-line. Simply choose the solution that is best documented.

Answer (score -1):

I found [this](http://wiki.awkwardtv.org/wiki/Linux_on_Apple_TV) wiki on how to install Linux on your Apple TV. Maybe, it works for you too :)

Comment: This wiki describes how to install a Gentoo-based system on the device. While I believe this might give best performance, stability and customization capabilities, it is definitely not suited for beginners. One must keep in mind that unless all the steps are performed with full understanding, various problems may arise.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: according to your answer, it's not suited for beginners anyway, so having directions will definitely make it an awful lot easier...